viewModel on Kotlin Multiplatform?
How do I import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel on Kotlin Multiplatform (iOS, web, desktop, Android)?
Attempts:
[versions]
androidx-activityCompose = "1.10.0-alpha02"
androidx-compose-runtime = "1.8.0-alpha03"
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel = "2.9.0-alpha04"
lifecycleViewmodel = "2.9.0-dev1873"

[libraries]
androidx-activity-compose = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-compose", version.ref = "androidx-activityCompose" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-compose = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose", version.ref = "androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel" }
androidx-runtime = { module = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime", version.ref = "androidx-compose-runtime" }
jetbrains-lifecycle-viewmodel = { module = "org.jetbrains.androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel", version.ref = "lifecycleViewmodel" }
lifecycle-viewmodel = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel", version.ref = "androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel" }

Then in kotlin.sourceSets.commonMain.dependencies of build.gradle:
runtimeOnly(libs.androidx.runtime)
runtimeOnly(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
runtimeOnly(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel)
implementation(libs.jetbrains.lifecycle.viewmodel)

Unfortunately that doesn't work:


Reusing lifecycleViewmodel = "2.9.0-dev1873", I was able to add:
lifecycle-viewmodel-compose = { module = 
                 "org.jetbrains.androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose",
                                version.ref = "lifecycleViewmodel" }

(with implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose) in my kotlin.sourceSets.commonMain.dependencies)

All my projects use this import statement now, instead of the one you're using
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

But I'm not even seeing the lifecycle dependency in my toml files anymore.  Is it possible you are missing the compose compiler and JetBrains Compose plugins that automatically add it?
Toml file:
[plugins]
jetbrainsCompose = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose-plugin" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }

Build.Gradle file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
}

Sorry for any typos.  Write this on my phone to avoid opening the laptop tonight.
